# how to increase the tabs width to the mouse position

Tags: c#, devexpress, tabcontrol

I'm developing a browser relying on `webbrowser` winform component.

I used `xtratabcontrol` in order to surf with tabs (DevExpress component) which has close button in its tabs.

I'm trying to achieve what internet explorer(its last version) does when closing a tab ; the other tabs are extended(their width increases) to reach the mouse poisiton (to enable closing tab after tab without moving the mouse)

this is the code which I added ( in close button click event)

```
        Point cursor = MousePosition;
        int x = cursor.X;
        int count = browserTabControl.TabPages.Count -1;// I don't want to include the last tab (which opens another tabs)

        int width = x / count;


        for (int i = 0; i < browserTabControl.TabPages.Count -1 ; i++)
                browserTabControl.TabPages[i].TabPageWidth = width;
```

I also tried to get the tabs whole width before removing the last tab, then to divide it on the new tabs count , and to set the result to each tab :

```
    int current_width = (browserTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1) * browserTabControl.TabPages[0].TabPageWidth;
        //..............some code removing the last tab (actually the tab before the last tab)
        //after removing the last tab
        int count = browserTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1;

        int width = current_width / count;


        for (int i = 0; i < browserTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1; i++)
            browserTabControl.TabPages[i].TabPageWidth = width;
```

the first code result
[image: the result is not accurate]

---

the second code result :

[image: the result is not accurate]

**Probably the problem is when I divide int/int I lose the rest of the division, I can get a double result , but the TabPageWidth is int.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
    // Initialization
    foreach(XtraTabPage page in xtraTabControl.TabPages) {
        if(page == addNewTabPage) continue;
        page.TabPageWidth = 100; // turn off headers auto-size
    }
}
void xtraTabControl_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ClosePageButtonEventArgs ea = e as ClosePageButtonEventArgs;
    if(ea.Page != addNewTabPage) {
        xtraTabControl.BeginUpdate();
        ((XtraTabPage)ea.Page).Dispose();

        int totalWidth = 0;
        var visiblePages =((IXtraTab)xtraTabControl).ViewInfo.HeaderInfo.VisiblePages;
        int totalHeadersGrow = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < visiblePages.Count; i++) {
            var pageInfo = visiblePages[i];
            if(pageInfo.Page == addNewTabPage) continue;
            totalWidth += pageInfo.Bounds.Width;
            totalHeadersGrow += (pageInfo.Bounds.Width - pageInfo.Page.TabPageWidth);
        }
        int count = xtraTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1;
        int width = totalWidth / count - totalHeadersGrow / (count + 1);
        foreach(XtraTabPage page in xtraTabControl.TabPages) {
            if(page == addNewTabPage) continue;
            page.TabPageWidth = width;
        }
        xtraTabControl.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

P.S. You can contact [DevExpress support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) directly (and I believe that this is the best way when running into issues when using their product) to get official answer in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HeaderAutoFill` feature for this. which will automatically fill the tabs to the client area; so there is no need for the user to move the mouse for closing multiple

```
this.xtraTabControl1.HeaderAutoFill = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
```

Comment: it's not working for my purpose, I also have a tab which I don't want to extend it (the last tab in the photo above), In addition, it doesn't extend the tabs to the mouse position ; I need to move the mouse to close...

Comment: IMO last one shouldn't be a tab, it should be a `CustomHeaderButton` to add a new tab. PS: my answer is alternate way of solving your problem with what is available out of the box not exactly what you asked.

Comment: if I remove the last tab and convert it to CustomHeaderButton will it work ? and can I put the button in the same place ?